# Añadir datos en objeto React

Tags: reactjs

Saludos deseo me ayuden con algo que no me funciona bien, lo que pasa es que deseo añadir un datos en un arreglo mediante una funcion pero en vez de añadirlo me lo sobremonta, no sé que está mal este es mi codigo en redux:

```
const [lista,setLista]=useState([])
const agregaLista=(id)=>{
    setLista([id])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que al hacer `[id]`, estás creando una lista completamente nueva, la cual, reemplaza a la anterior. Si lo que quieres es añadir un elemento a la lista, debes guardar el valor de la lista en una variable, a la cual se le agregara el nuevo elemento. Una vez modificada la lista, vuelves a hacer el `set` para guardarla con el nuevo elemento.

```
const [lista,setLista]=useState([])
const agregaLista = (id) => {
    let lt = lista;
    lt.push(id);
    setLista(lt);
}
```